# trying to convert a String like 2/1/2021 0:09(iam getting this string from csv file) to LocalDateTime

Tags: java

iam getting an error as "Text '2/1/2021 12:09:54 AM' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 14". the string value i want to convert is like 2/1/2021 0:09. below is my conversion code. thanks in advance

```
public static LocalDateTime converttodate(String str) {
    DateTimeFormatter dateformatter=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yyyy H:mm");
    LocalDateTime localdatetime=LocalDateTime.parse(str, dateformatter);
    
    return localdatetime;
}
```

Comment: Your format pattern does not include the seconds part of the date string. Shouldn't the pattern be `M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss` ? Or simply remove the seconds part from the string you are trying to parse.

Comment: It seems like you _thought_ that your CSV file contained dates in `M/d/yyyy H:mm` format, but it actually contained dates in `M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss` format. Better check the CSV file.

Comment: The String values i am getting from csv files does not have seconds . i suspect its something to do with time zone but i dont know how to

Comment: example value from csvfile 2/1/2021 0:55

Comment: @suryateja But from the error it seems that the input to your method from the csv is `2/1/2021 12:09:54 AM`

Comment: @user15358848 i wonder it resolved when i use pattern "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss a" but the value in file is exactly like "2/1/2021 0:11". when i tried to out the value iam getting from csv file to console it look likes "2/1/2021 0:11:56 AM"   (there is nothing like 2/1/2021 0:11:56 AM in the file).

Comment: yes When i printed out the it looks like 2/1/2021 0:11:56 AM. but the orginal value in file is 2/1/2021 0:11 i have no idea how and why :56 AM added.